# JSONB output from object.query() results in syntax error on raw sql

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, jsonb

I am quite new to django and JSONB and I use this following syntax to execute a search on JSONB data fields:

```
obj=SomeModel.objects.filter(data__0__fieldX__contains=search_term)
```

.. and it works as intended. Now, I print out the `obj.query` for the above statement and I get:

```
SELECT * FROM "somemodel_some_model" 
WHERE ("somemodel_some_model"."data"
#> ['0', 'fieldX']) @> '"some lane"'
```

However, when I excecute the above using:

```
obj=SomeModel.objects.raw(`query statement above`)
```

I get an error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "["
LINE 3:         #> ['0', 'fieldX']) @> '"some lane"'
```

I presume I am not escaping the "[", and I have tried using a backslash before, but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you do is smth like:

```
with c(j) as (values('
[
  {
    "fieldX": -20,
    "fieldY": 40
  },
  {
    "fieldX":10,
    "fieldY": 0
  }
]
'::jsonb))
select j #> ['0', 'fieldX'] from c;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 13: select j #> ['0', 'fieldX'] from c;
```

what you have to do is smth like:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('
[
  {
    "fieldX": -20,
    "fieldY": 40
  },
  {
    "fieldX":10,
    "fieldY": 0
  }
]
'::jsonb))
select j #> '{0,fieldX}' from c;
 ?column?
----------
 -20
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

`text[]` is array, but in Postgres array are presented as `'{}'` or `array[]`, not just `[]`

so

```
 j #> array[0,'fieldX']::text[] from c
```

would also work

Comment: Thanks a tonne for this @Vao - REALLY helps. I have seemed to solve that problem now. I have shamelessly edited the question to ask for another, where,  when I use the same logic on a case insensensitive lookup, I get a syntax error near `%`. It just seems really odd, and I wonder if it is somehow related.

Comment: please don't mix posts. just ask a new question

Comment: I have now moved it to a new question here and accepted your answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764138/django-postgres-like-query-syntax-error-at-or-near