# django postgres LIKE query syntax error at or near "%"

Tags: django, postgresql

In django, to query JSONB, I do:

```
    cursor.execute("""\
    SELECT * FROM "somemodel_some_model" 
    WHERE UPPER(("somemodel_some_model"."data" 
    #>> array[0,'fieldX'])::text[]) 
    LIKE UPPER(% %s %)
    """,[my_string])
```

.. and I get:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know the above cant be true because when I use the ORM to achive this using:

```
obj=Some_Model.objects.filter(data__0__fieldX__icontains=search_term)
```

.. I get the results.
To investigate this, I drop to SQL and do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM "somemodel_some_model"
WHERE UPPER(("somemodel_some_model"."data" 
#>> array[0, 'fieldX'])::text[]) 
LIKE UPPER(%my_search_string%)
```

..but, I get:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"

So, the question is, do I need to escape %? Seems odd

Answer (score 1):

When using cursor.execute like syntax should be  LIKE `%% string %%` or if you use column and  LIKE `%%  || column || %%`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM somemodel_some_model WHERE UPER((somemodel_some_model.data #>> array[0,'fieldX'])::text[])  LIKE UPPER(concat('%', %s, '%')) ",[my_string])
```

because if you use `UPPER(% %s %)`

resulting query would be like `UPPER(% 'your_string' %)` (I don't know if django quotes literals) or `UPPER(% your_string %)` - both cases not valid for SQL, So you either gave to construct `[%my_string%]` in django, or use concat as in example above

Comment: unfortunately, when I use `LIKE UPPER(concat('%', %s, '%'))` it still gives the same error (I presume there is a typo in your statement with a missing `)`)

Comment: yes - there were a typo. are you sure in your `"""`?.. there's no need in `"somemodel_some_model"` - you can use `somemodel_some_model`, same for tablename

Comment: I am not totally sure I understand your last comment, but, when I use `somemodel_some_model` for my other queries, it seems to execute perfectly.